# Futile attempt to run regular expression find/replace in MS Word using groups on Mac

Tags: regex, string, macos, replace, ms-word

According to the [received wisdom](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f) MS Word  *(more or less)* supports **find/replace** with use of regular expressions. I have a [simple regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/qG8qD5/1):

```
^(C[[:alpha:]]*)(\d*)(.*)$
```

That I'm running on the data:

```
indSIMDdecile
CSdeccrim12006
CSdeccrim12006
CSdeccrim12009
CSdeccrim12009
CSdeccrim12012
CSdeccrim12012
CSdeceduc12004
CSdeceduc12004
CSdeceduc12006
CSdeceduc12006
CSdeceduc12009
CSdeceduc12009
CSdeceduc12012
CSdeceduc12012
CSdecemp12004.x
```

I'm interested in returning the first word prior to the digit **1**, which works as demonstrated [on regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/qG8qD5/1).

## Problem

I would like to the same but in MS Word *(v. 15.18 on Mac)*. After getting error messages of trying to supply unsuitable syntax I learned that MS Word does not support to the full regex syntax. I simplified my expression to something on the lines:

[image: Expression in MS Word]

but the search does not find any strings and nothing gets replaced. Hence my questions, *is it possible to use MS Word on Mac with regex*?

---

*The linked [help website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f) hints that something like that should be possible, but so far now luck.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is "no", if you mean "Does Mac Word have a UI feature that lets you use one of the modern dialects of regex?" Word's Find/Replace only supports its own Regular Expression syntax.

In this case, I think the following will give you what you need:

Find with wildcards:

```
(C)([!1]@)(1)
```

and a replace by

```
\1
```

(If you also had to find "`C1`", then that doesn't work, and unfortunately nor does

```
(C)([!1]{0,})(1)
```

because Word does not allow 0 in the `{,}` pattern)

But there is a problem with "@". If the text the "@" is looking for is long, the find/replace may fail. There is supposed to be a 255 limit, but it seems rather more arbitrary than that. (I have long suspected a buffer overrun type error in the Word code, but perhaps there is a simpler explanation).

If you mean, "is there any way to use modern regex with Word?", then the answer is "Yes, but you only get to operate on a *copy* of the text in the document. You will need to create your own code to do the 'replace' part of the find replace, and that means that you would have to deal with any of the issues such as preserving formatting that Word's built-in find/replace *might* get right for you.

On the Windows side, people who want a better regex than Word's often use VBScript's regexp object because it is easily used from VBA. VBA itself only really has the "like" operator, which also only has fairly crude pattern matching abilities. I think there are examples of VBScript rexexp use on StackOverflow. On the Mac side, you would either have to use VBA and "shell out" to one of the built-in Mac/Unix utilities to do your finding (and perhaps replacing), or perhaps use Applescript or Javascript application scripting to do it. As far as I can remember Applescript does not have a 'modern' regex built-in either.

[As a bit of history, Word's "regular expressions" were I think introduced in Word 6, around 1993, at a time when most dialects of regex were much more crude than they are today. I don't think Word's version has moved along much at all - it probably added some Unicode support at some point, but that's probably about it. I assume that people using modern regex don't regard it as regex at all, and I personally prefer not to call Word's Regular Expressions 'regex' precisely for that reason.]